# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' , Unable to locate resourceFile in source-sets

Tags: android, android-xml

Whenever I made any change to an XML file from the project and tried to run it, I got this error-

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate resourceFile (D:Q\app\build\intermediates\merged-not-compiled-resources\debug\layout\notification_action.xml)
> in source-sets.

For running the project I need to do Build > Clean Project every time if I make any changes to XML.

Below is my grade file -

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxx"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'


}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found by several testing that proguard rule is the issue for this error. Changing the proguard rules for debug solves the issue. Just need to set `shrinkResources false` in the debug buildTypes.

```
 buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

Comment: What if you actually want to shrinkResources?

Answer (score 32):

In short:
"clean project and move on"

Details:
Go to the "build tab" in the android studio > then click on "clean project".
enjoy!

Comment: This isn't an answer. The OP already stated they knew they can clean as a workaround.

Comment: this works when I generate APK

Answer (score 8):

"Clean Project and then run the app", this work for me you can also try this

Answer (score 7):

Restarting Android Studio was the solution in my case.

There is no need to set `shrinkResouces false`. I have set it to true and it works completely fine.

Answer (score 2):

R8 is the new code shrinker from Google, and it’s enabled by default when you build a release APK or AAB. To disable R8, pass the --no-shrink flag to flutter build apk or flutter build appbundle.

To get .aab(appbundle),

```
flutter build appbundle --no-shrink
```

To get .apk,

```
flutter build apk --no-shrink
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case,I build my apk. I click build ->generate signed bundle or APK,
then I get the error

```
Unable to locate resourceFile
```

I delete the .idea folder in my project.

[image]

Then I build my apk again, it's no more error. it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing Android Studio's cache resolved the issue for me.

Select 'File > Invalidate Caches' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button.

Comment: I usually do this, but today I just restarted the build, and it solved the problem in less time than "Invalidate and Restart".

Answer (score 0):

**Build** >> **Rebuild Project** solved my probem

Answer (score 0):

just press Shift + F10 again.This is the fastest way, less time consuming than Clean -> Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in AGP, see: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206674992

Apparently fixed in 8.0.