# Error when Building apk for Particular Flavor in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have implemented flavors in my flutter application. When I try to build apk using this command

```
 flutter build apk --release --flavor development -t lib/main_dev.dart
```

I get the following error, but on trying the above command for a second time, the apk is generated successfully.

### **What went wrong:**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevelopmentReleaseResources'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate resourceFile (/flutter_app/build/app/intermediates/merged-not-compiled-resources/development/release/drawable/abc_dialog_material_background.xml) in source-sets.
```

Here's the defination of flavors in `app/build.gradle`

```
    sourceSets {
        customer {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/customer/res']
        }

        staging {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/staging/res']
        }

        development {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/development/res']
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"
    
    productFlavors {

        customer {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

        }

        staging {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

        }

        development {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

        }
    }
```

### **Default Config**

```
defaultConfig {
      
        applicationId "com.example.app"
  
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName 1.0.0
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your targetSdk version and minSdkVersion

Comment: I have added the `buildConfig`.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72212885/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-unable-to-locate-resource